# Convert SVG map path elements to XY coordinates

Tags: dictionary, svg, processing

I am working with SVG maps to plot some data. I need to obtain the XY coordinates of the map border which is described as SVG path elements.

Here is a path element I am working with

```
<path id="path9" fill="#FEFEE9" d="M920.059,219.437c0.127,1.93,0.201,3.877-0.029,5.803c-0.178,1.481-1.184,5.296-0.36,6.535
    c1.039,1.563,4.821,3.389,6.673,3.596c1.609,0.18,5.432-0.127,6.617,0.441c0.4,0.874-0.001,1.517-0.168,2.396
    c-0.069,0.37,0.633,3.127,0.752,3.716c1.961,1.148,3.784,2.506,5.716,3.698c1.087,0.67,2.413,1.076,3.386,1.913
    c0.365,0.314,0.62,0.738,0.922,1.109c-0.016,1.154,0.506,3.383,1.086,4.377c0.135,0.232,0.789,1.036,1.063,1.116
    c2.15,0.636,3.828-0.681,5.791-1.207c0.861-0.231,1.766-0.3,2.611-0.604c0.881-0.316,3.353-2.991,3.869-3.849
    c2.478-1.148,3.059-0.635,5.38-2.728c1.101-0.992,4.065-4.614,5.544-4.467c0.447,0.044,0.893,0.115,1.336,0.174
    c2.113,0.279,2.188,0.777,3.697,2.003c0.047,0.038,1.65,0.608,1.873,0.69c0.804-0.67,1.566-1.387,2.301-2.132l0.605-5.29
    c0.268-2.339,0.69-6.967,3.691-7.332c2.594-0.315,4.773,1.322,7.347,1.322c0.692,0,4.183-1.588,4.554-2.079
    c0.514-0.679,0.42-2.522,0.443-3.369c0.111-0.162,0.236-0.396,0.37-0.536c0.461-0.488,2.526-0.31,3.205-0.366
    c1.001-0.082,1.985-0.316,2.976-0.476l0.729-0.638c2.227-0.24,4.326-1.121,6.552-1.373c0.393-0.569,2.722-2.864,3.288-3.083
    c2.049-0.792,8.942-1.78,9.938-3.577c0.465-0.841-0.443-2.831,0.233-3.917c0.923,0.353,1.54,1.016,2.575,1.151
    c-0.166-1.493-1.109-2.96-0.582-4.482l1.215-0.951c1.877,0.542,3.863,0.518,5.793,0.69c1.293-0.857,4.697-2.529,6.225-1.804
    c1.408,0.668,0.947,4.653,3.629,5.542c0.715-0.29,1.691-1.052,1.951-1.8c-0.627-2.991-0.695-2.316-2.588-4.539l0.305-2.169
    l1.818-1.26l2.143-0.162c0.751,0.488,1.803,0.99,2.443,1.588c0.814,0.761,2.076,3.795,2.711,4.324
    c0.436,0.363,1.728,0.591,2.296,0.6c0.26,0.004,1.422-0.569,1.741-0.709l0.5-0.751c-0.501-0.794-1.596-1.51-2.432-1.917
    c-0.246-1.607-1.506-2.717-2.244-4.094l0.496-0.642l0.84-0.301c0.77,0.181,2.451,0.857,2.799,1.599
    c1.125-0.17,2.313-0.491,3.454-0.343c3.124,0.405,9.103,2.854,8.682,6.78c2.558,2.942,4.063,3.596,6.68,5.965
    c1.634,1.479,2.741,3.536,3.966,5.347c0.487,0.72,0.84,1.612,1.467,2.222c1,0.973,2.729,1.023,3.312,2.433.......//more elements//................z"/>
```

This is just a small snippet of the actual path element.

It contains a lot of 'c' and 'l' elements. The image is 1807x1331 px. I need to obtain the XY co-ordinates so that I can use the border to mark boundaries in my visualization.
I am using Processing 2.0 for Visualization.

Can I convert the path elements to XY coordinates? Or is there any way to mark that border? Imagine I have to make cells (Voronoi cells) within the territory boundary. Currently they extend beyond the border since I can't confine them because I dont have the border coordinates.

Comment: could you post the full svg ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Here is the svg image I am working with
[link] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Afghanistan_location_map.svg
I have downloaded the full res map.

Comment: And I need to find the Border co-ordinates of Afghanistan.

Comment: Are you looking to find the X,Y coordinates of the bounding box of the path? A bounding box is the minimum enclosing rectangle that encloses the path.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides I am trying to find the co-ordinates of the contour of Afghanistan i.e. the border (actual territorial border) of the country and not the bounding box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You can use PShape's [getVertexCount()](http://processing.org/reference/PShape_getVertexCount_.html) and [getVertex()](http://processing.org/reference/PShape_getVertex_.html) methods:</strike>

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < yourPShape.getVertexCount(); i++) println("vertex["+i+"]:"+yourPShape.getVertex(i));
```

I encountered an error when using `getVertex()`:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
```

so getVertex() might still be a bit buggy.
Luckily [getVertexX()](http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PShape.html#getVertexX%28int%29),[getVertexY()](http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PShape.html#getVertexY%28int%29) still work:

```
void setup(){
  PShape map = loadShape("Afghanistan_location_map.svg");
  size((int)map.width,(int)map.height);
  //fetch the border shape - peaked at the path name using Illustrator
  PShape border = map.getChild("path157");
  //manually traverse the path
  beginShape();
  for(int i = 0 ; i < border.getVertexCount(); i++){
    vertex(border.getVertexX(i),border.getVertexY(i));
  }
  endShape();
}
```

Note that you can have lines(l) and curves(c) so it's worth not just looking at the regular [PShape reference](http://processing.org/reference/PShape.html) but also the [JavaDocs](http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/index.html) for functionalities you might need. Depending on how complex your svg is you need check the [vertex code](http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PShape.html#getVertexCode%28int%29)( `VERTEX, BEZIER_VERTEX, CURVE_VERTEX, or BREAK`).

Comment: I tried the above method but its not working. getVertex doesn't return the Co-ordinates.

Comment: @Vijay I've tested with your shape and have updated the code to work

Comment: @Vijay Also, you can check if a point is within the shape using PShape's contains(x,y): http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PShape.html#contains(float, float) method but [be aware](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327606/pshapesvg-contains-function-doesnt-work-when-scale-is-applied/12350632#12350632) if you use transformations on the PShape instance.

Comment: Thanks for the code and the useful pointers. I think this might just solve my problem (especially the contains(x,y) function). I'll try these things out. Thanks a ton!